# Java: OpenCSV escape character in fields

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I have my input file with quoted fields. Below is how I am initializing the CSV reader

```
CSVParser parser = new CSVParserBuilder().withSeparator(CSVParser.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR).build();
CSVReader reader = new CSVReaderBuilder(new FileReader("abc.txt")).withCSVParser(parser).build();
```

With the following input, it reads properly.

```
"1","abc","this works properly with ""quotes"" as well"
```

With the following input, it fails

```
"1","abc","this fails with \""backslash\"" and ""quotes"". "
```

I know in java backslash is an escape character. Is there a workaround to read the above line properly? Unfortunately, I can't change the input format as its generated by our client's legacy system.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/properly-handling-backslashes-using-opencsv

Comment: I will close this question as I used the following 

    CSVParser parser = new CSVParserBuilder().withSeparator(CSVParser.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR)
    .withQuoteChar(CSVParser.DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER).build();